# TIBCO SPOTFIRE 7.5 SORT BY HIERARCHY

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire

How can I sort a horizontal bar chart by value, but per hierarchy?
I need sort each group by value. If I sort by value, spotfire mix the groups.

thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your hierarchy on your category axis?

Comment: My hierarchy is on category axis and have 4 level. When I move with trellis from level 1 to level 2 I want to sort by value the bar chart inside each group.